# Explode by parenthesis PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have for example: "Color (YELLOW)"

and I want to obtain "Color"

So I made:

```
$driver_bo = explode('/\\(', $driver);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[0]);  

$driver_bo = explode('/(', $driver);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[0]);

$driver_bo = explode('(', $driver);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[0]);
```

Ant nothing of that works

Comment: Ok, I dont know what I made.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rizer123 is right. Try this:

```
$driver =  "Color (YELLOW)";
$driver_bo = explode('(', $driver);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[0]); 
echo($driver);
```

The output is "Color"

Answer (score 0):

You may use two different functions for this situation.

[explode :](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.explode.php)

```
$driver = "Color (YELLOW)";
$driver_bo = explode('(', $driver);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[0]); 
var_dump($driver);
```

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.preg-match.php) :

```
$driver = "Color (YELLOW)";
preg_match('/(.*?)\(.*?\)/si', $driver, $driver_bo);
$driver = trim($driver_bo[1]);  
var_dump($driver);
```

Both of them returns "Color".